# Cassandra compaction by API

Tags: cassandra, cql, jolokia

I'm running Cassandra 2.1.2, and I want to do a compaction programmatically, e.g. by sending an HTTP request somewhere, not by running nodetool compact on the command line. Is this possible? I have Jolokia, if that's any help. I can also use CQL, just not nodetool compact.

Comment: Look at NodeTool code - can be done pretty easily through JMX https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/tools/NodeTool.java